# Finding f(0.5) given maclaurin-serie of a function

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

For a function we have that $f(x) = -9$ at $x = 0$. The n'th derivative of the function at $x=0$ is given as $$f^{n}(0) = 4\frac{n!}{5^n}$$ for $n \geq 1$. $f(x)$ is also analytical, which means that it is equal to it's maclaurin-serie on the interval (-5, 5). Find $f(0.5)$.

If f(x) is equal to it's maclaurin-serie on (-5, 5), 0.5 is part of this interval. If I simply plug in n = 0.5 i get the wrong answer. What am I overlooking here?

Comment: What exactly are you plugging $n = 0.5$ into?  (Also, in English, it's usually "series" for both the singular and plural, isn't it?  I suppose there could be a variant there.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Write down the series

$$f(x)= f(0)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}4(x/5)^n$$

and compare this with the infinite geometric sum

$$\dfrac{1}{1-u}=1+u+u^2+u^3+...$$

with $u=x/5$.

Comment: This led me to $-9+4/9 = -\frac{77}{9}$ which seems to be the right answer. Thank you for the hint sir